# How to resolve "Index of" problem on nginx

Tags: nginx

ON nginx I configured this role :

```
  On server file:
    location ~ .php$ {
    root /var/www/public;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/public$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

  # On Domain file
  location /support {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  autoindex on;
  autoindex_exact_size off;
  }
  #for admin panel 

  location ^~ /support/admin {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php;
  autoindex on;
  autoindex_exact_size off;
  }
```

I solved 403 error problem when I added autoindex on; line,
but I see "index of support" message when I Click on my Domain
and when I want to Click on index.html file, this file not to show, and instead of it, download is done.
How can I resolve this problem and What is my problem in my shared code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`location /support {
default_type "text/html";
types { application/octet-stream html; }
…
}`

Comment: the problem persists